# PHP calculate total and split

Tags: php, summary, divide

How to calculate total and split on 4 without duplicate line with php?
Example:

- 27
- 43
- 57
- 29
- 12
- 23
- 44
- 23
- 52

I want to divide summary by 4 without duplicating line. My point is to have 4 persons with closest results.

Last few hours I'm looking in google to find something similar but I couldn't.

Thank You!

Comment: You can post the code you have tried. It's helpful to see the mistake you made.

Comment: `4 persons with closest results` what is a `person`? what is a `result`? how is this data generated? Maybe each number is a person's score?

Comment: What is `without duplicating line`? What line?

Comment: Yes, each number is a pearson's score in mysql table and it it should not duplicate.

Comment: Use the `+` operator then divide on `/ 4` and checking for duplicates on the array.

Comment: *"Yes, each number is a pearson's score in mysql table"* - oh, you mean it gets better. Plenty of ways to do this.

Comment: oh, you mean it's not a PHP array, but MySql table?.. What about updating the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of guesswork/write this for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you want:

```
sort($array); // Put the array into numeric order
$group_by_4 = array_chunk($array, 4);
```

`array_chunk` will return a 2-dimensional array, where each element is a group of 4 elements of the input array.

Create `$array` by fetching the elements from the table into an array.

```
while ($row = $conn->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row['score'];
}
```